# Bubblegum plot for expression data and percentage occurrence in cell types

Tags: r, heatmap, rna-seq

good morning!

I hope everyone is well.
I have a question about the input file for the bubblegum plot. I have two .csv files that I assembled from Single-Cell RNAseq expression data: the first, percentage of occurrence of this expression in different cell types, and the second, the gene expression values in these different cell types. I want to plot a graph like the one suggested by Federico Giogi. My question is: what should my input file look like, if I plot the percentage of occurrence data as the bubble area and the expression values as the color pattern of these bubbles?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Michele

Comment: You question is not really clear because we do not know which function are you planning to use. Please update your question with code, dataset example and and an example of your desired output

Comment: Agreed with Basti. In case you need more info on how to make it easier for us to help you, have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It would also be helpful to show us what the graph looks like (Stack Overflow has many people who are good at R, but not very many people who are familiar with molecular biology or who might know who Federico Giogi is!)